# Sites for purchasing iOS source code?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an idea for a iOS app. However, as I lack the required programming skills, but do have general programming skills in java and vb, I think I could implement my (relative simple) idea if I only got my hands on some source code that is somewhat close to what I need.

I've been searching around for some time now but I'm unable to find a active community that offers this kind of service. There are a bunch of "inactive" (only a few things for sale) sites, but why are there so few? I thought the iOS market was booming with apps and code.
Are there legal issues?

Anyway, if I do not want to hire a coder for my job, where should I look for suitable code to buy?

My app idea requires a database, displaying of images and text, a search function... nothing high tech really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the reason is that there are such a large number of samples and tutorials available for free that if you are willing to pay for source code that is specific the the kind of app you want, it would probably be cheaper, or at least easier with better results, to just hire a programmer.

I cant provide you with any sites that offer this kind of service, as I do not know of any, but I can suggest some tutorials and links from which you could make a very good attempt at your app if it is as straightforward as you say.

eBooks:

```
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Essentials
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_iOS_4_Development_Essentials_Xcode_4_Edition
```

Tutorials:

```
http://www.raywenderlich.com/
```

The eBooks I have linked are both absolutely fantastic and one of the few xCode 4.0 books that I was able to find that seemed to be of an actual usable quality. They both contain easy to follow and clear tutorials on simple and more advanced aspects of programming for iOS.

Ray's site is an immensely helpful resource as it contains both a very active forum base for iOS programming in addition to a constantly growing tutorial collection as there are 4-5 people that constantly are creating new tutorials that the community votes on and suggests every week. It contains some more advanced topics than the above books and I would recommend looking at it after doing a few walk through/tutorials from the books.

The sample code from Apple goes without saying of course :D

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Apple's sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) in their iOS dev library? That might be a good way to get jump started.

Unfortunately, **I don't think there are any easy shortcuts to making a solid iPhone app**. Why not try to teach yourself Objective-C, using online resources like the [Stanford iPhone dev course](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can buy individual iOS components online, but I've never seen somewhere where you can buy a framework for an entire app. This is probably because most apps are quite unique, so it only really makes sense to hire a developer if you don't want to write it yourself.

Instead, I'd suggest simply learning iPhone development, especially considering you have prior knowledge in other languages. For starters, look at Apple documentation and sample code, in addition to the WWDC videos, which are on http://developer.apple.com,NAND the Stanford iPhone development course videos, which is free on iTunes U.